# Exception ex_trans_cexcept on SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, compatibility, sql-server-2019

In our program (C#), we use the system stored procedure `sp_cursorprepexec`.

Now, on a somewhat newer customer environment, we get the following error message:

> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Recording the program crash on SQL Server Profiler shows the following error message:

> Exception ex_trans_cexcept.

SQL Server Version there is "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
Sep 24 2019 13:48:23
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)"

*Script*

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
declare @p2 int
set @p2=0
declare @p7 int
set @p7=default
exec sp_cursorprepexec @handle=@p1 output,@cursor=@p2 output,@paramdef=N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 int, @3 varchar(50), @4 varchar(10)',@stmt=N'Select *
From [TABLE]
Where CustomerNumber = @0 
  And VersionNumber = @1 
  And ContactNumber = @2 
  And (om_db.[CUSTOMER]_AccessValidation (@3, BankAccountId, @4, ''Read'', ''DO.BankAccount'') = 1) 
Order by AccountNumber, CustomerNumber, VersionNumber, ContactNummer, AccountIdentifier',@scrollopt=4097,@ccopt=98305,@rowcount=@p7 output,@0=205536,@1=0,@2=14,@3='[CUSTOMER]',@4='[USER]'
select @p1, @p2, @p7
```

**Solution description**
changing the compatibility level of the database from SQL Server 2019 (150) to SQL Server 2017 (140) solved the problem.

Does anyone has a clue what probably could cause this error?

Comment: Have you considered update your instance? You're well over 2 years behind in updates, and 2019 has several bugs in it's RTM version.

Comment: Thanks, server-version is managed by customer, we currently have no ability to update. But yes you're right, version is very outdated.

Comment: since there is a scalar udf om_db.CUSTOMER_AccessValidation() check for scalar udf inlining and try an execution with a query hint : OPTION (USE HINT('DISABLE_TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING'))